# TypeScript function that conditionally requires second parameter based on first parameter requirement

Tags: typescript

I want to write a fully type-safe `get` function that accepts the property as 1st argument, and *maybe* a default value as 2nd argument, but only if the type of the 1st argument could be undefined.

Examples:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
  totalKids?: number
}

// defaultValue as 2nd argument IS NECESSARY because "totalKids" could be undefined in Person
safeGet<Person>('totalKids') // Error: safeGet expected 2 arguments but got only 1.
safeGet<Person>('totalKids', 4) // OK
safeGet<Person>('totalKids', 'four') // Error: string is not assignable to number
safeGet<Person>('totalKids', undefined) // Error: undefined is not assignable to number

// defaultValue as 2nd argument is NOT necessary because "name" is always a string in Person
safeGet<Person>('name') // OK
safeGet<Person>('name', 'John') // Error: safeGet expected 1 argument but got 2.
```

Please notice how on the last `totalKids` example (`safeGet<Person>('totalKids', undefined)`), even though `Person['totalKids']` can be undefined, the 2nd argument `defaultValue` exclude that option.

What I currently have:

```js
function safeGet<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T, V extends T[K] = T[K]>(
  key: K,
  ...defaultValue: V extends null | undefined ? [NonNullable<V>] : []
) {
  return (obj: T): V => {
    if (obj[key]) {
      return obj[key] as V
    }
    return defaultValue[0] as V
  }
}
```

But it never expects a 2nd argument (always as `never)`:

```js
safeGet<Person>('name') // Compiles OK
safeGet<Person>('name', 'John') // Errors OK

safeGet<Person>('totalKids') // Compiles but should not
safeGet<Person>('totalKids', 'four') // Errors but not because of arg not expected (never)
safeGet<Person>('totalKids', 4) // Errors but should compile
safeGet<Person>('totalKids', undefined) // Errors but because of arg not expected (never)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bunch of stuff going on here, but the major problem is that TS has no partial type parameter inference; you can't call `safeGet<Person>(...)` and manually specify `Person` like that and get the compiler to infer the other types; they will fall back to their defaults.  If you're okay making a curried function you can do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/W4p3XW); or if not, you'd need a dummy parameter like [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/Na0gEw).  If either of those meets your needs I'll write it up. If not, can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: @jcalz I'm sorry I totally forgot to mention it's a curried function, so it's correct use would be: `safeGet<Person>('name')({ name: 'Jcalz' }) // "Jcalz"` or `safeGet<Person>('totalKids', 4)({}) // 4` and `safeGet<Person>('totalKids', 4)({ totalKids: 3 }) // 3`

Comment: No, I'm saying you have to curry it further to separate the `T` from the `K`, did you see the code in my links?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain that styled-components "pass along" the generic to `safeGet` inside the template string. Could you check my exact use case? https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-oskar-em7pr?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Like [this I guess?](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-morning-gcjci).  I'm not sure how much effort I'm supposed to put in working with use cases not explicitly written out in the question.

Comment: My apologies I didn't want to bring react/styled-components because I thought it'd reduce my chances of getting answered. Your last solution isn't working for me, it says `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`, is it working for you? I can edit my question and bring it closer to my use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238370/discussion-between-bernamariano-and-jcalz).

Comment: What is my "last solution"?  The one with the dummy parameter or the codesandbox link?  "Is it working for you"?  Every piece of code I have posted is working for me in my browser, so maybe there's some mismatch between what I'm looking at and what you're looking at.

Comment: Chat scares me, always feels like I've agreed to meet a stranger in a dark alley; I want to stay here where the rest of the public is!

Comment: No problem for me at all, let's keep it in here. By "last solution" I meant the codesandbox one, maybe there's a mismatch because the code in there is exactly what I sent you...

Comment: Does [this link](https://tsplay.dev/wQK9Jm) work instead (or [this](https://tsplay.dev/N52XVm) to see how it constrains things)?  You might need to open it in Chrome (I've noticed some weirdness with TS playground in other browsers recently).  If you see an error in there let me know.

Comment: The former link compiles as intended and the latter breaks as intended. So what I'm getting is, as you mentioned in your first comment, it is impossible for TS to accomplish this without explicitly passing the generic type to safeGet? Simply `color: ${safeGet('bgColor', 'yellow')};` isn't viable?

Comment: How would the compiler know that `safeGet('bgColor', 'yellow')` is okay if you don't mention `Colored` anywhere?  You could make it so that `safeGet()` accepts any parameters at all and then returns something that accepts only a value of a compatible type (so `safeGet('bgColor', 'yellow')`'s return would accept anything extending, say, `{bgColor?: string}` and then return a `string`.  But that's weird and wouldn't look at all like any of the code in your question (`safeGet('foo',123)` would succeed). I mean, *you're* the one who wrote `safeGet<Person>` and now you want to not write `<Person>`?

Comment: I might be losing steam here.  If you want to see any of the solutions I've suggested written up as an answer, I can do that.  If you want to refactor the code in your question to show use cases you actually want to support I can possibly come back later after that's over and take a look.  Or if you want something else I haven't been able to figure out, maybe someone else will put eyeballs on this and make a better suggestion.  Let me know.

Comment: I truly appreciate your time, thank you for the help. As I said earlier, I don't know how to explain it but styled-components "passes along" to the callback function the generic you gave it beforehand, at the component declaration call `const Button = styled.button<Colored>`. I've done it on other functions before, without explicitly mentioning the type at the function call level, only by giving it to styled-components at component declaration level it was able to figure the entire type all the way down, but I had to use `ts-toolbelt/Function/Narrow` to do it. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: Okay, good luck!

Comment: [Working perfectly](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-oskar-em7pr?file=/src/App.tsx)! I was almost there, thanks for the examples! @jcalz